# Logstash 6.2 - full persistent queue (wrong mapping?)

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

My queue is almost full and I see this errors in my log file:

```
[2018-05-16T00:01:33,334][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Could not index event to Elasticsearch. {:status=>400, :action=>["index", {:_id=>nil, :_index=>"2018.05.15-el-mg_papi-prod", :_type=>"doc", :_routing=>nil}, #<LogStash::Event:0x608d85c1>], :response=>{"index"=>{"_index"=>"2018.05.15-el-mg_papi-prod", "_type"=>"doc", "_id"=>"mHvSZWMB8oeeM9BTo0V2", "status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"failed to parse [papi_request_json.query.disableFacets]", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"i_o_exception", "reason"=>"Current token (VALUE_TRUE) not numeric, can not use numeric value accessors\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.BytesReference$MarkSupportingStreamInputWrapper@56b8442f; line: 1, column: 555]"}}}}}
[2018-05-16T00:01:37,145][INFO ][org.logstash.beats.BeatsHandler] [local: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:5000, remote: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:50222] Handling exception: org.logstash.beats.BeatsParser$InvalidFrameProtocolException: Invalid Frame Type, received: 69
[2018-05-16T00:01:37,147][INFO ][org.logstash.beats.BeatsHandler] [local: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:5000, remote: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:50222] Handling exception: org.logstash.beats.BeatsParser$InvalidFrameProtocolException: Invalid Frame Type, received: 84

...

[2018-05-16T15:28:09,981][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] retrying failed action with response code: 403 ({"type"=>"cluster_block_exception", "reason"=>"blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)];"})
[2018-05-16T15:28:09,982][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] retrying failed action with response code: 403 ({"type"=>"cluster_block_exception", "reason"=>"blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)];"})
[2018-05-16T15:28:09,982][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] retrying failed action with response code: 403 ({"type"=>"cluster_block_exception", "reason"=>"blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)];"})
```

If I understand first warning, problem is with mapping. I have a lot of files in my queue Logstash folder. My questions is:

1. How to empty my queue, can i just delete all files from logstash queue folder(all logs will be lost)? And then resend all the data to logstash to proper index?
2. How can I determine where exactly is problem in mapping, or which servers sending data of wrong type?
3. I have pipeline on port 5000 named testing-pipeline just for checking if Logstash is active from nagios. What is that `[INFO ][org.logstash.beats.BeatsHandler]` logs?
4. If I understand correctly, `[INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch]` is just logs about retrying to process logstash queue?

On all servers is FIlebeat 6.2.2. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. All pages in queue could be deleted but it is not the proper solution. In my case, the queue was full because there was events with different mapping of index. In Elasticsearch 6, you cannot send documents with different mapping to the same index so the logs stacked in queue because of this logs (even if there is only one wrong event, all others will not be processed). So how to process all data you can process an skip the wrong one? Solution is to configure DLQ ([dead letter queue](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/dead-letter-queues.html)). Every event with response code 400 or 404 is moved to DLQ so others could be process. The data from DLQ can be processed later with pipeline.
2. Wrong mapping can be determined by error log "error"=>`{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", ..... }`. To specify exact place with wrong mapping, you have to compare mapping  of events and indices.
3. `[INFO ][org.logstash.beats.BeatsHandler]` was caused by Nagios server. The check did not consist of valid request, that's why the Handling exception. The check should test if Logstash service is active. Now I check Logstas service on `localhost:9600`, for more info [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/node-stats-api.html).
4. `[INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch]` means that Logstash trying to process the queue but index is locked (`[FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)]`) because the indices was set to read-only state. Elasticsearch, when there is not enough space on server, automatically configure indices to read-only. This can be change by `cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.low`, for more info [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/disk-allocator.html).